# Visio 2013 Change Shape tool loses text contained in custom shapes

Tags: microsoft-visio-2013

I am working on some process flows for a customer that has requested customized process/subprocess boxes.  I have made several adjustments to the Master Shape and the ShapeSheet data to get these to work correctly.  I am working on an ongoing issue now where if I use the Change Shape tool in Visio 2013 I can correctly change Shapes but the replacement shape does not retain the text that was included in the target shape.

My Master Shape is basically a process shape with a square overlaid on the top right corner.  I made all of the necessary alterations to the text boxes and connection points and then Grouped everything together in the Master Shape.  I am not sure if the Grouping is causing the conflict or if there is another configuration/command needed to pull across text from a Grouped Shape.  I have tried to set up the ReplaceCopyCells using a DEPENDSON statement with no luck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was your grouping action that caused the Change Shapes task to lose the text.
The correct procedure would be use Convert to Group on the Process shape in the Master. Then you would need to make the existing rectangle transparent, add two sub-shapes into the group. The first to be a replacement for the rectangle that you have made transparent, and the second being your smaller rectangle in the top right corner.
[image: Enhanced Process Master shape]
You should ensure that the Match master name on drop property is ticked, otherwise you could accidently end up with the Process shape from the Microsoft stencil.
[image: Match master name on drop]
You should then find that Change Shape does not remove the text.
[image: Replaced shape maintains text]

Comment: David- I appreciate the response.  I am following your instructions and they seem straightforward enough.  When I go in to test the shapes in a test file after updating the Master Shapes Visio 2013 seems to throw an error every time.  I am getting:  Visio Internal Error: # -1 Action 2051: Change Shape.  It recommends closing and opening the file and restarting Visio.  None of these actions seems to be working.  Any suggestions?  Thanks again-

Comment: It is sounding like there is something amiss in your document already. Have you tried my instructions on a brand new diagram? I have seen errors like yours when there has been some bad cell references. Try ActiveDocument.Clean in the ImmediateWindow

Comment: I actually did just that and was able to get it to work.  Thank you for the suggestion.  Now I am struggling with the fact that we typically have a fill color assigned to the "square" with text designating the actor/role.  I believe that the solution you provided would fix our issue if there were no fill color to the shape.  I am not sure how to manage it if we are trying to keep the same fill color and text in the square.